# Faster way to estimate cell height in a CollectionView

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, cgsize

I have an infinite scroll in my UICollectionView and I've noticed that the way I estimate my cell height is the bottleneck of my collection view. It causes some long delays the more I scroll my collection view.

**Is there a better way to estimate the heights of my cells?**

The cells have different heights because I have a `UILabel` in each of them. I assign a NSMutableAttributedStrings of different lengths to those UILabels:

```
let paragraphStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
paragraphStyle.alignment = .justified
paragraphStyle.lineSpacing = 5.0

let attributedText = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "   \(post.caption)", attributes: [NSAttributedStringKey.font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 15), .paragraphStyle: paragraphStyle, .baselineOffset: NSNumber(value: 0)])

attributedText.append(NSAttributedString(string: "\n\n", attributes: [NSAttributedStringKey.font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 4)]))

let timeAgoDisplay = post.creationDate.timeAgoDisplay()
attributedText.append(NSAttributedString(string: timeAgoDisplay, attributes: [NSAttributedStringKey.font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 14), NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor: UIColor.storiesLightGray()]))

captionLabel.attributedText = attributedText
```

My `sizeForItemAt` method. I've noticed that calling `dummyCell.layoutIfNeeded()` makes my app very slow once I have more than 200 items in my collection view:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {

        var height: CGFloat = 180

        let frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: view.frame.width, height: height)
        let dummyCell = HomePostCell(frame: frame)

        dummyCell.post = presenter.posts[indexPath.item]
        dummyCell.layoutIfNeeded()

        let targetSize = CGSize(width: view.frame.width, height: 5000)
        let estimatedSize = dummyCell.systemLayoutSizeFitting(targetSize)

        let newHeight = max(height, estimatedSize.height)

        return CGSize(width: view.frame.width, height: newHeight)
 }
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ideally you should not use `systemLayoutSizeFitting` in your `sizeForItemAt`, because, as you say, it is slow.

You could precache some cell data, calculate the sizes, and store them in an array or similar, so that `sizeForItemAt` merely has to do the lookup in the array — which is fast.

And you don't really need to use `systemLayoutSizeFitting`, either; you can use your knowledge of the label size and contents to calculate the size (e.g. using NSAttributedString measurement methods).

That is what we used to do before `systemLayoutSizeFitting` or auto layout existed, and it remains far faster.

Comment: See for example my discussion here: http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch21.html#_variable_row_heights It's about table view rows, not collection view items, but the idea is exactly the same.

Comment: @matt Precache means: before reloading the collection view, calculate the sizes of cells based on string sizes and store them in array. And use that calculated array in `sizeForItemAt', right ?