# Table view stucking a lot

Tags: swift, xcode, uitableview, autolayout, uitextview

I am using a `tableView` to show text only. Inside cell, I am using a `UITextView` with dynamic height and `linkDetection` with html text converted to `attributedString`.

I am parsing the html text to attributed text inside my `model` class below way:

```
if let nodeValue = dict["blurb_link"]{
    blurb_link = nodeValue as? String
    let attrString = NSMutableAttributedString(attributedString: (blurb_link?.html2AttributedString)!)
    atr_blurb_link = attrString
}
```

`html2AttributedString` in an `extension` of `String` which returns an `attributedString` from html text.

I am populating my cell inside cell subclass via below way,

```
textViewBlurbLink.attributedText = model.atr_blurb_link
```

But the problem that is happening is, whenever a new cell is loaded, the tableview stucks for a fraction of second which make the `tableView` scrolling a bit jerky and disturbing to user.

There are no images, no videos no heavy task inside cell which can cause a jerky scroll. Please tell me what could be possible reason of this jerky and hiccup scrolling?

**EDIT:**

The layout of my cell is:

[image]

After getting response I have populated tableView below way:

```
TSNetworkManager.getDataFor(Request: dataRequest, success: {response in
        //print(response.responseObject!)
        let model = TSLatestModel.init(WithDictionary:         response.responseObject as? [String : Any])
        completion(model)
        tblLatest.reloadData()
    }, failure: {error in
        onError(error)
})
```

and inside `cellForRowAtIndexPath`

```
let modelLatestDetails = model?.data![indexPath.section].items![indexPath.row]
cell.setupCellData(model: modelLatestDetails!)
```

Inside the `setupCellData` in `tableViewCell` subclass I am setting the text into `textView`.

**EDIT2:**

This the total codebase of my `model class`

```
class TSLatestModel: TSModelBase {
var data : [LatestListModel]?
override init(WithDictionary dictionary: [String : Any]?) {
    super.init(WithDictionary: dictionary)
    if let dict = dictionary{
        if let nodeValue = dict["data"] {
            data = [LatestListModel]()
            for latest in nodeValue as! [Any]{
                let model = LatestListModel.init(WithDictionary: latest as? [String:Any])
                data?.append(model)
            }
        }
    }
}
}

class LatestListModel: NSObject {
var storyname : String?
var main_title : String?
var color : String?
var issuedate : String?
var formatted_issue_date : String?
var id : String?
var cat_name : String?
var cat_id : String?
var order : Int?
var items : [TSLatestDetailsModel]?
var itemsModified : [TSLatestDetailsModel]?
init(WithDictionary dictionary: [String : Any]?) {
    super.init()
    if let dict = dictionary {
        if let nodeValue = dict["items"] {
            items = [TSLatestDetailsModel]()
            itemsModified = [TSLatestDetailsModel]()
            for item in nodeValue as! [Any] {
                let model = TSLatestDetailsModel.init(WithDictionary: item as? [String : Any])
                items?.append(model)
                if !((item as! [String : Any])["one_liner"] as! String).isEmpty {
                    let filteredArray = itemsModified?.filter({$0.one_liner == ((item as! [String : Any])["one_liner"] as! String)})
                    if filteredArray?.count == 0 {
                        let model = TSLatestDetailsModel.init(WithDictionary: item as? [String : Any])
                        itemsModified?.append(model)
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        if let nodeValue = dict["item_list"] {
            items = [TSLatestDetailsModel]()
            itemsModified = [TSLatestDetailsModel]()
            for item in nodeValue as! [Any] {
                let model = TSLatestDetailsModel.init(WithDictionary: item as? [String : Any])
                items?.append(model)
                if !((item as! [String : Any])["one_liner"] as! String).isEmpty {
                    let filteredArray = itemsModified?.filter({$0.one_liner == ((item as! [String : Any])["one_liner"] as! String)})
                    if filteredArray?.count == 0 {
                        let model = TSLatestDetailsModel.init(WithDictionary: item as? [String : Any])
                        itemsModified?.append(model)
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        if let nodeValue = dict["_id"] {
            storyname = nodeValue as? String
        }

        if let nodeValue = dict["order"] {
            order = nodeValue as? Int
        }

        if let nodeValue = dict["category"] {
            cat_id = (nodeValue as! [Any])[0] as? String
        }

        if let dictStoryType = dict["_id"] as? [String : Any] {
            if let nodeValue = dictStoryType["issuedate"] {
                issuedate = nodeValue as? String
            }
            if let nodeValue = dictStoryType["formated_issue_date_title"] {
                formatted_issue_date = nodeValue as? String
            }
            if let nodeValue = dictStoryType["id"] {
                id = nodeValue as? String
            }
            if let nodeValue = dictStoryType["category_name"] {
                cat_name = nodeValue as? String
            }

        }

        if let nodeValue = dict["name"] {
            storyname = nodeValue as? String
        }

        if let nodeValue = dict["story"] {
            storyname = nodeValue as? String
        }

        if let nodeValue = dict["main_title"] {
            main_title = nodeValue as? String
        }

        if let nodeValue = dict["color"] {
            color = nodeValue as? String
        }

    }
}
}

class TSLatestDetailsModel: NSObject {

var __v : Int?
var _id : String?
var title : String?
var topic_key : String?
var blurb : String?
var blurb_link : String?
var atr_blurb_link : NSMutableAttributedString?
var formated_issue_date : String?
var formated_issue_date_item : String?
var formated_issue_date_title : String?
var issue_link : String?
var issue_title : String?
var issue_date : String?
var one_liner : String?
var main_title : String?
var source : String?
var source_link : String?
var isActive : Bool?
var isDeleted : Bool?
var isfavourite : Bool?
var story_order_number : Int?
var story_type : String?
var categories : [String]?
var story_type_model : TSStoryTypeDetailsModel?
var favourite_category_id : String?

init(WithDictionary dictionary: [String : Any]?) {
    super.init()
    if let dict = dictionary{
        if let nodeValue = dict["__v"]{
            __v = nodeValue as? Int
        }
        if let nodeValue = dict["_id"]{
            _id = nodeValue as? String
        }
        if let nodeValue = dict["title"]{
            title = nodeValue as? String
        }
        if let nodeValue = dict["topic_key"]{
            topic_key = nodeValue as? String
        }
        if let nodeValue = dict["blurb"]{
            blurb = nodeValue as? String
        }
        if let nodeValue = dict["blurb_link"]{
            blurb_link = nodeValue as? String
            let attrString = NSMutableAttributedString(attributedString: (blurb_link?.html2AttributedString)!)
            atr_blurb_link = attrString
        }
        if let nodeValue = dict["formated_issue_date"]{
            formated_issue_date = nodeValue as? String
        }
        if let nodeValue = dict["issue_date"]{
            issue_date = nodeValue as? String
        }
        if let nodeValue = dict["issue_link"]{
            issue_link = nodeValue as? String
        }
        if let nodeValue = dict["issue_title"]{
            issue_title = nodeValue as? String
        }
        if let nodeValue = dict["one_liner"]{
            one_liner = nodeValue as? String
        }
        if let nodeValue = dict["main_title"]{
            main_title = nodeValue as? String
        }
        if let nodeValue = dict["source"]{
            source = nodeValue as? String
        }
        if let nodeValue = dict["source_link"]{
            source_link = nodeValue as? String
        }
        if let nodeValue = dict["isActive"]{
            isActive = nodeValue as? Bool
        }
        if let nodeValue = dict["isfavourite"]{
            isfavourite = nodeValue as? Bool
        }
        if let nodeValue = dict["story_order_number"]{
            story_order_number = nodeValue as? Int
        }
        if let nodeValue = dict["story_type"]{
            story_type = nodeValue as? String
        }
        if let nodeValue = dict["formated_issue_date_title"]{
            formated_issue_date_title = nodeValue as? String
        }
        if let nodeValue = dict["formated_issue_date_item"]{
            formated_issue_date_item = nodeValue as? String
        }
        if let nodeValue = dict["favourite_category_ids"] {
            if (nodeValue as! [String]).count > 0 {
                favourite_category_id = (nodeValue as! [String])[0]
            }
        }
        if let nodeValue = dict["story_type"] {
            let model = TSStoryTypeDetailsModel.init(WithDictionary: nodeValue as? [String : Any])
            story_type_model = model
        }
        if let nodeValue = dict["category"] {
            categories = [String]()
            for category in nodeValue as! [String] {
                categories?.append(category)
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

The `cellForRowAtIndexPath`:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "TSArchiveDetailsCell") as! TSArchiveDetailsCell
    cell.delegate = self


    if !((favoriteDetilsModel?.data![indexPath.section].items![indexPath.row].source!.isEmpty)!) {
        cell.viewFav.isHidden = false
    } else {
        if favoriteDetilsModel?.data![indexPath.section].storyname?.lowercased() == "brush up" {
            cell.viewFav.isHidden = false
        } else {
            cell.viewFav.isHidden = true
        }
    }

    if isSayItOnRounds {
        let modelLatestDetails = favoriteDetilsModel?.data![indexPath.section].items?.filter({$0._id! == selectedItemId})[0]
        cell.setupCellData(model: modelLatestDetails!)
    } else if isBrushUp {
        let thirdBrushUpItemModel = favoriteDetilsModel?.data![indexPath.section].items![2]
        if thirdBrushUpItemModel?._id == selectedItemId {
            let modelLatestDetails = favoriteDetilsModel?.data![indexPath.section].items?.filter({$0._id == selectedItemId})
            cell.setupCellData(model: modelLatestDetails![0])
        } else {
            let modelLatestDetails = favoriteDetilsModel?.data![indexPath.section].items![indexPath.row]
            cell.setupCellData(model: modelLatestDetails!)
        }
    } else {
        let modelLatestDetails = favoriteDetilsModel?.data![indexPath.section].items![indexPath.row]
        cell.setupCellData(model: modelLatestDetails!)
    }
    return cell
}
```

Comment: Add here full code of this cell.

Comment: `model?.data![indexPath.section].items![indexPath.row]` - data and items are simple arrays or your overload "[.. ]" (Subscript)?

Comment: There are nested array of dictionaries Sir!

Comment: there are multiple sections and under sections there are multiple rows.

Comment: Add here full code of this cell and model.

Comment: Vasily Bodnarchuk:  Sir, I have added my total codebase. Please have a look once.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172901/discussion-between-ipeter-and-vasily-bodnarchuk).

Comment: No need to guess. Use Instruments. Run time profiler. Scroll. Stop. Read what Instruments tells you.

Comment: Also, note that self-sizing cells _do_ slow things down. You are forcing layout to happen in order to determine the size of the cell just before it appears on screen, and that takes time.

Comment: matt: Then what is the alternatives for self sizing cells?

Comment: See e.g. my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50519089/341994. But do not optimize prematurely; do what I said before, use Instruments and find out what the problem _is_ so that you solve the _right_ problem.

Comment: I need to learn using instruments for that sir, I have a lot of things to learn. :) I am trying hard to catch that and solve the problem. :) Thank you so much.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172931/discussion-between-ipeter-and-matt).

Comment: Hey matt, I have tried Intruments, ran time profiler, scrolled, stopped, scanned but I was not able to find any of my methods which causing maximum cpu usage.

Answer (score 1):

Possible problems:

1. **Cell layout.** I need to see, how do you make layout and reuse cell.
2. **Parsing data and drawing cells at the same time.**
   You need to create all data before (`tableView.datasource = self or tableView.reloadData()`). So, your [AttributedString] must be ready before reloading tableView. Do not parse data in `cellfoRowAtIndexPath`.

Also, check that tableView call `cellfoRowAtIndexPath` only one time for each cell during cell lifetime.

Comment: Vasily Bodnarchuk: I have edited my question, can you please have a look once.